# Getting a 0 in all my calculations when inputting values, but the math works out on paper. No errors or warnings from compiler

Tags: visual-c++

Okay I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong here, but any kind of help would be vastly appreciated. I When i input the values for the pay rate and the hours worked each week (which is wk1-wk5), i am getting a zero for all my calculations.

**Here is source Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double tax = 0.14;

int main()
{   
int wk1,wk2,wk3,wk4,wk5;
wk1 = wk2 = wk3 = wk4 = wk5 = 0;

double payrate;
payrate = 0;

cout << "Please enter the payrate for employee." << endl;
cin >> payrate;

cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week one:" << endl;
cin >> wk1;

cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week two:" << endl;
cin >> wk2;

cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week three:" << endl;
cin >> wk3;

cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week four:" << endl;
cin >> wk4;

cout << "Please enter employee's total hours for week five:" << endl;
cin >> wk5;

    int thours = wk1 + wk2 + wk3 + wk4 + wk5;
thours = 0;

    double gross = payrate * thours;
double taxes = tax * gross;
double net = gross - taxes;
double clothes = 0.10 * net;
double supplies = 0.10 * net;
double remaining = net - clothes - supplies;
double bonds = 0.25 * remaining;
double pbonds = 0.50 * bonds;

cout << "Here is income before taxes: " << gross << endl;
cout << "Here is income after taxes: " << net << endl;
cout << "Here is clothes and accesories: " << clothes << endl;
cout << "Here is School supplies: " << supplies << endl;
cout << "Here is personal bonds: " << bonds << endl;
cout << "Here is parents bonds: " << pbonds << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to do the calculations after reading the values, not before. Otherwise, the values all evaluate to 0.

Comment: Look at where you're performing the calculations, then look at where you're requesting user input. That's called "putting the cart before the horse".

Comment: Oh yes bahaha! Thank you both for that. Okay i so i moved the calculations to the bottom after the prompt/input statements except where i declared wk1-wk5 and pay rate. I still got a zero when i ran the program. So i ask for input, i have the input declared, user inputs values for payrate and hours worked each week which should then all add up. Im not sure where i messed up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly assume that by assigning an expression such as `double x= y*3` to a variable, that its value will always be determined by the value of `y` throughout your program. That's not the case.

What this does is that the value in `y` is copied, multiplied by 3 and then assigned to x. So if at the time of assignment, `y` was 10, it will always be 10 no matter how `y` changes in the future *unless you reassign `x` with the new value of `y`*.

So in order to solve your problem, perform the calculations after you receive the values of your variables.

**+**

Also, this line:

```
int thours = wk1 + wk2 + wk3 + wk4 + wk5;
thours = 0;
```

After you assign the `wk` variables to `thours`, you set it back to zero. What you should be doing:

```
int thours = 0;
thours = wk1 + wk2 + wk3 + wk4 + wk5;
```

Comment: Okay i see what your saying. I edited my code and moved my calculations to the bottom after user is prompted to input values. I am still getting a zero when i moved them down.

Comment: After you declare `thours` and assign it the hours, you set it back to zero. From there on, it's like falling dominoes.